# "svn up" is not restoring sub folders which I have deleted

Tags: svn

I have deleted some subfolders from my working copy. But now when I am using `svn up`, It is not restoring deleted folders.

Comment: Did you schedule those deletions for commit (e.g. `svn rm somedir`), or just delete them using your file explorer/shell commands?

Comment: Just deleted them using file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) to restore the deleted subtree. Like this:

```
svn revert name-of-deleted-folder
```

Comment: But in Windows updating working copy restores deleted folders also. But when I am updating code in linux, Folders are not getting restored.

Comment: svn up does not clobber your uncommitted changes on any platform. If you've deleted a folder in your working copy, that counts as an uncommitted change. If you revert the uncommitted change (your deleted folder), then svn will restore it from the repo.

Comment: The scenario is like this, I checked out code from repository and I did not make any changes and I delete some sub folders (which are also in repositoy) from my working copy. When I use `svn up` command these folder are not restored when I am doing this in linux but it `windows` it does.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on on your windows setup but svn up is not supposed to restore deleted directories that are under revision control. The behavior you described in linux is the correct one. The correct way to restore deleted folders that are under revision control using svn on any platform is to use svn revert, not svn up.